# Solution for word-break:break-all styling in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap, html-table

I am trying to wrap text inside a td and using the below style

```
word-break:break-all
```

Works perfectly fine in IE, but fails in Firefox, read that this isnt supported!
tried the solution given in http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/02/firefox-ie-word-wrap-word-break-tables.html. Didnt seem to work either, Any solution for this?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: The solution from the blog works for me perfectly.

Comment: I tried applying the class HardBreak at td level and it didnt work,is that all you did?

Comment: Yes i only added the class name to the td and thats it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally had some trouble with this also. But i managed to get it working:

```
.hardBreak {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+, 6, 7, 8 compability-mode */
  -ms-word-break: break-all; /* Internet Explorer 8 */
}
```

I hope this helps.

The last option is needed while having IE8 native mode. This works for me and is tested in FF8, IE 7, 8compability, 8native, Chrome.

Comment: Aword-break: break-all;nswer is getting old..since it comes up in Google searches, I'd like to suggest to update it with new info: now `word-break: break-all;` works in Firefox, too :)

Answer (score 4):

word-wrap will only work for inline-block or block elements. So, you have to change your element type. Like:

```css
.example {
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Good point. Had this problem on my side and fixed with inline-block. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use
word-wrap: break-word;
It will surely work!!

Comment: Give the code to your answer and make it little brief.

Answer (score 1):

With

`display : block;`

It is ok

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the solution you mention has worked for some time; it may have (inadvertantly?) worked on some past versions of Firefox, but it does not look like one that could be expected to do the job (`pre-wrap` shouldn’t be expected to break words).

The way to make Firefox treat a point as permissible direct line break opportunity is the `<wbr>` tag—not in any specification, but widely supported. Normally it is best used by inserting it at *suitable* points, but at the extreme, you could even put it between any two characters (presumably, you would use preprocessing, server-side scripting, or client-side JavaScript to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

It should work in all browsers (so long as you have a fixed width on the div/cell you're applying it to...

Comment: If you post the actual HTML, I can take a look. Do you have a fixed width on the td tag?